# Find out if two dictionaries result in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have two dicts, where the dict inside the dict stands for the values in the other dict:

```
dict1 = {1:{1,3}, 2:{2}}
dict2 = {1:{5}, 3:{1}}
```

I am trying to find out, if the combination would result in a loop, for example:

dict1: 1 -> dict2: 3 -> dict1: 1;
This would result in a loop, so my script should throw an error.

dict1: 2 -> not in dict2; Not a loop would be okay

dict1: 1 -> dict2: 1 -> 5 not in dict 1; Not a loop would be okay

Any ideas how I could solve that problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you want to find loops of length 2, or any length? e.g. 1->3->5->6->1 is also a loop, right?

Comment: At any length :)

Comment: Then add it to your question explicitly, at least two other answerers were confused...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Effectively, your question is about finding a cycle (of any length, if I understand correctly) in a bipartite graph.

With some minor pre-processing, you can use the `networkx` package to find if there is any cycle in your graph. `networkx` deals with bipartite graphs, but let's just rename out nodes and not need to use the bipartite trait directly.

To pre-process the dictionaries, we add a prefix 'a' to the nodes in the first dict and a prefix 'b' to the nodes in the second (and not forget to add the prefixes to the edge targets):

```
dict1 = {'a'+str(k): set(map(lambda x: 'b'+str(x), v)) for k, v in dict1.items()}
dict2 = {'b'+str(k): set(map(lambda x: 'a'+str(x), v)) for k, v in dict2.items()}
```

Now our dictionaries look like this:

```
{'a1': {'b3', 'b1'}, 'a2': {'b2'}, 'b1': {'a5'}, 'b3': {'a1'}}
{'b1': {'a5'}, 'b3': {'a1'}}
```

We merge them together to create a single dictionary:

```
dict3 = dict1
dict3.update(dict2)
```

And turn that dictionary into a (directed!) graph:

```
import networkx as nx
g = nx.DiGraph(dict3)
```

If you're so inclined, you can draw the network (with `nx.draw_networkx(g)`) to see what came out:
[image: networkx graph]

Well, we can see the cycle between 'a1' and 'b3'. To find them automatically - and this is the point of this answer - we can just use the following command:

```
nx.simple_cycles(g)
```

which in this case returns a generator object which yields the cycles (in this case, (`list(nx.simple_cycles(g))` is `[['b3', 'a1']]`.

But you don't want the whole list; you just want your code to throw an exception if the list is not empty. So, you can use:

```
assert(not(next(nx.simple_cycles(g), None))
```

And you're done!

Comment: I think that is the best solution for my problem, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to know if there is a loop between the two dictionaries you can use this code:

```
for key, values in dict1.items():
    if any([v in dict2 and key in dict2[v] for v in values]):
        print('loop found')
```

Otherwise, if you want to know where the specific loop is, you need to break out the iteration over `values` in the above code:

```
for key, values in dict1.items():
    for v in values:
        if v in dict2 and key in dict2[v]:
            print('loop found from ' + str(key) + ' through value ' + str(v) + ' back to ' + str(key))
```

For your sample data the output is either `loop found` for the first code snippet or `loop found from 1 through value 3 back to 1` for the second.

Comment: This is more elegant than mine, so I'm upvoting it :)

Comment: I like this one too, although it is limited to a length of 2!

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the problem right, you could do something like:

```
for idx_set in dict1.values():
    in_dict2 = (idx for idx in idx_set if idx in dict2)
    for idx in in_dict2:
        for idx2 in dict2[idx]:
            if idx2 in dict1:
                print('detected a loop for %s' % idx_set)
```

This looks pretty verbose but it's relatively easy to understand what's going on.

Comment: Will this find loops of length > 2?

Comment: It just checks whether any entries in `dict2` that are referred to in `dict1` in turn refer back to `dict1`. So it should find loops of any length, if I understand you correctly.

Comment: will this find something like a1 -> b1 -> a2 -> b2 -> a1?

Answer (score -1):

## This should do it, Put an Error raise where I have 1/0 //SW

```
dict1 = {1:{1,3}, 2:{2}}

dict2 = {1:{5}, 3:{1}}

start_key = 1

a = list(dict1[start_key])

b = list(dict2)

if a == b:
    
    1/0
```

Comment: It looks to me like you're only searching for loops of length 2, this is not a solution.